# Amortized time per operation using disjoint sets

Tags: big-o, disjoint-sets, amortized-analysis

I happened to read on Wikipedia that the amortized time per operation on a disjoint set (union two elements, find parent of a specific element) is O(a(n)), where a(n) is the inverse Ackermann function, which grows very fast.

Can anyone explain why this is true?

Answer (score 0):

Well, the Wikipedia page has a citation.  If you're that interested, check it out.  If you're at college that should be easy, if not, just find a nearby college and use their library (they don't care if you're not a student).

Answer (score 0):

Well, that would be rather hard to explain, because it isn't true. It's the non-inverse Ackermann function that grows like a rocket on steroids, the inverse Ackermann grows very slowly.

[This](http://compgeom.cs.uiuc.edu/~jeffe/teaching/algorithms/notes/10-unionfind.pdf) gives you the theoretical background.

Answer (score 0):

There is a proof of the fact in [Introduction to Algorithms](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0262033844). It's a fairly popular read it seems, and your city or school library might have a copy. I've also seen copies floating about on the Internet but the legality of those is probably questionable.

EDIT: a [chunk of the proof](http://books.google.com/books?id=NLngYyWFl_YC&lpg=PP1&dq=introduction%20algorithms&pg=PA511#v=onepage&q&f=false) appears to be readable on Google Books.